# Python > Check an int is between two other int

Tags: python-3.x, function, exception, error-handling, syntax

The function in question

```
def IsInRange(lr,hr,num):
    return lr < num < hr
```

later, we ask for the input.

```
lr = floaterror('Provide your low range number, please: ')
hr = floaterror('Provide your high range number, please: ')
num = floaterror('Provide number to range find, please: ')
```

The assignment asks we say if it's in range. So, I did:

```
if IsInRange(lr, hr, num) == False:
    print(num, "is not in range.")
elif IsInRange(lr, hr, num) == True:
    print(num, "is in range.")
```

It works. But let's say,

```
lr = 1
hr = 1
num = 1
```

It says 1 isn't in range...I want to create an exception where if this happens it prints "Your check value cannot equal your range." instead of "# is not in range." But I am struggling with this. I cannot change the IsInRange function return per assignment. And I'm sure this is part of it as well as the full code I've written. I have included it below.

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
def sub(num1,num2):
    return num1-num2
def mlt(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2
def dvd(num1,num2):
    return num1/num2
def IsInRange(lr,hr,num):
    return lr < num < hr

end = True
print("Basic Math Function and In-Range Checker")
while end == True:
    user = input('Please press Enter to continue with a simply mathtastical time, or "q" to quit. ')
    if user == 'q':
        print('You chose to avoid the math! Exiting!')
        break
    else:
        keep_on_rolling = True
        while keep_on_rolling:
        #1st exception to catch invalid entries, that is, not integers.
        #You'll be prompted to enter a correct value.
            def floaterror(one):
                while True:
                    try:
                        return float(input(one))
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Numbers only, please. Try again, with digits!")
        #End 1st catch
            num1 = floaterror('Give us your first number and press enter, please: ')
            num2 = floaterror('Give us your second number and press enter, please: ')
            lr = floaterror('Provide your low range number, please: ')
            hr = floaterror('Provide your high range number, please: ')
            num = floaterror('Provide number to range find, please: ')
            print('The result of', num1, 'added with', num2, 'is', add(num1,num2))
            print('The result of', num1, 'subtracting', num2, 'is', sub(num1,num2))
            print('The result of', num1, 'multiplied by', num2, 'is', mlt(num1,num2))
        #2nd error catch, tryig to destroy the universe by dividing by zero.
            try:
                print('The result of', num1, 'divided by', num2, 'is', (dvd(num1,num2)))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("Uff da. We don't divide by zero in this house.")
        #End 2nd catch.
            else:
                if IsInRange(lr, hr, num) == False:
                    print(num, "is not in range.")
                elif IsInRange(lr, hr, num) == True:
                    print(num, "is in range.")
            break
```

I didn't keep any of my failed code.
But I tried adding an exception under else: which you can't do, I tried if lr == num == hr to print my desired answer. I tried adding an exception above where the function in question comes in. I tried adding an exception after the input. But constantly getting syntax errors or if no errors, it just doesn't seem to appear at all. I also tried defining a new function that uses the inputs and still nothing.

Comment: can you add code inside the isInRange without changing the return?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this "instructor" doesn't like deviance from his dictation. He also states that his Introduction To Python isn't about coding, but promoting conversation to enter the IT field... He also says I do not understand functions but that my functions are fine (all in the same comment, lol) This post is mor about a personal feature I want as I will not include it in my submission. You get marked down for creativity.

Comment: But if push comes to shove, If the way it's designed cannot accommodate what I want, I will change it for myself going forward. I just want to create clean code and get the results I want. this is just a class after all, not real life.

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of `if lr == num == hr: raise ValueError("<Error message>")`?

Comment: I have but I cannot get it to work without a syntax error, meaning I'm putting it in the wrong place, most likely, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here
if (not IsInRange(lr, hr, num)) and (not lr == hr and not num == hr):
    print(num, "is not in range.")
elif IsInRange(lr, hr, num):
    print(num, "is in range.")
else:
    print("Your check value cannot equal your range.")
```

```
if your 
lr = 1
num = 1
hr = 1
 print - "Your check value cannot equal your range."
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).